# Are there no comments on this StackExchange?

Tags: support, comments

I don't see any comments or commenting functionality. Is this by design or a limitation of the beta?

Comment: Testing comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see comments fine on substrate.stackexchange.com

For example, this [question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/818/telemetry-for-local-network) has several comments.

Maybe try reloading the page?

Comment: Thank you. Clearly an issue on my side.